# How do we raise an event which stores the file name in SQS queue thru lambda, when a new file is uploaded in Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-event-bridge, amazon-s3

How do we raise an event which stores the file name in SQS queue thru lambda, when a new file is uploaded in Amazon S3 bucket

Answer (score 1):

AWS S3 offers a feature specifically for this use case called "Amazon S3 Event Notifications".

You can configure your S3 bucket to send out a "notification" (also called event) to a SQS queue.

Furthermore, you can fine-tune for which specific "event" you want to get a notification. You could configure the bucket to send an event to SQS only when an object with the extension `.jpg` was deleted for example.

You should read the very detailed documentation by AWS to find out more:

[Amazon S3 Event Notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html)